# Logic app or Web app?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to decide whether to build a Logic App or a Web App.

It has to do things I'm quite comfortable doing in C#: receive messages in various formats (a few thousand per day), translate them, make API calls and forward them. None of the endpoints are widely used, so the out-of-the-box connectors won't be a benefit. Some require custom headers, the contents of which are calculated using a hashing algorithm. Some of the work involves converting Json into XML and vice-versa.

From what I've read, one of the key points of difference of Logic Apps are that you don't have to write any code. Since our organisation is actually quite comfortable with code, that doesn't feel like it'll actually be a benefit.

Am I missing something? Are there any compelling reasons why a Logic App would be better than a Web App in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to keep away from Logic Apps for these reasons:

1. It is not supported outside Azure.  We aren't tied to any other providers, and to use Logic Apps would break that independence.
2. I don't know how much of the problem is readily soluble using Logic Apps. (It seems I will be solving all sorts of problems which wouldn't be problems if I was using C#.  [This article](https://connectedsystems.com/blog/Blogs/Azure-Logic-apps-by-a-developer-point-of-view.aspx) details some issues encountered while developing a simple process using an earlier version of Logic Apps.)
3. Nobody has come up with an argument more compelling than the reasons I've given above (especially the first one) why we *should* use it, so it would be a gamble with little to gain and plenty to lose.

Comment: If you love to write lots of code and require cloud independence than custom code is a fine solution for you.  But to clarify some of your bulleted remarks:

Comment: -entered too soon
If you love to write lots of code, don't mind spending a lot of time and energy understanding 3rd party APIs and message formats, and require cloud independence then custom code in a portable container is a fine solution for you.  To clarify some of your bulleted remarks:
- The article referenced in your second bullet point is really really outdated and commenting on an early pre-release of the product.  All of those issues mentioned in that article have been addressed in the current generally available version.
- Logic Apps tooling is supported in both VS 2015 and VS 2017

Comment: @KevinLam not sure what you mean about spending time and energy understanding 3rd party APIs.  If you're talking about the ready-made connectors of Logic Apps, then that doesn't apply to my situation.  Zendesk's web hook is the most widely used of the endpoints I'll be dealing with, and there's no connector for that. The rest are quite specialised, and quite simple to talk to anyway. Thanks for the correction to point 3.

Comment: great discussion. Logic Apps has a ZenDesk connector.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list doesn't list it.  Maybe I stumbled upon an incomplete list, but this is exactly the kind of obstacle Logic Apps will present me with.

Answer (score 4):

Using Logic Apps has a few additional benefits over just writing code which include:

- Out of box monitoring.  For every execution you get to see exactly what happened in each step of the process with a monitoring view that replicates your Logic App design view.
- Built in failure handling. Logic Apps will automatically retry calls on failure cases and also allows you to either customize the retry policy or have a custom retry policy with a do-until pattern.
- Out of box alerting. You can configure alerts to inform you of failures.
- Serverless. You don't worry about sizing or scaling and you pay by consumption.
- Faster development.  Logic Apps allows you to build out the solution faster especially as you consider that you don't have to code for monitoring views, alerting, and error handling that comes out of the box with Logic Apps.
- Easy to extend. If you are already using a Logic App access to over a 125 connectors to various services will make it easy to add business value or making it smarter by including things like cognitive services to your workflow with very little extra effort.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Are Logic Apps are capable of all the things I described? E.g. the custom, constantly-changing auth headers for API calls?

Comment: Yes you can add custom headers to http request that are dynamically assigned at runtime including auth.  Logic Apps also has built-in expressions to convert between XML and JSON.

Comment: Thanks Kevin - that's helpful. Do you have any links to resources showing how to do the custom headers thing?

Comment: You can populate the headers referencing values at runtime. You can look at the following articles on the HTTP action:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#http-action
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#use-the-http-action

Comment: Thanks for you input Kevin.  In the end the most compelling reason was that it tied us to Azure, whereas our other technologies are more portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of Logic Apps as an orchestrator - something that takes external pieces of functionality, and weaves a workflow together.

It has nothing to do with your requirement of "writing code" - your code can be external functions on any platform - on-prem, AWS, Azure, Zendesk, and all of your code can be connected together using Logic Apps.

Regardless of which platform you choose, you will still have cross-cutting concerns such as monitoring, logging, alerting, deployments, etc, and Logic Apps addresses very robustly all of those requirements.